# Is there a options in Plane2Cylinder distort of imageMagick to make a Image like bellow?

Tags: c, lua, imagemagick, magickwand

When I used Plane2Cylinder distortion I got Image like below. But I want the effect like second image. Please go through my code.

```
local nelem = 1 -- number of args
local arg = ffi.new("const double[?]", nelem, {100})
-- local methos = ffi.new("const int", 15)
return handle_result(self, lib.MagickDistortImage(self.wand,13, nelem, arg, 1))

ffi.cdef([[  typedef void MagickWand;
typedef void PixelWand;
MagickBooleanType MagickDistortImage(MagickWand *wand, DistortMethod method, const size_t, const double *args, const MagickBooleanType bestfit);
```

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**
for fred's script I used below command

```
bash -x ./cylinderize.sh -m vertical -r 366.34955984688 -l 188.179 -w 16.6667 -p 23.428692808745 -n 96.097053534591 -e 1.75 -a 0 -v background -b none -f none -o -86-80.8315 single_color.png single_color.j.png
```

Below is my modified image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment than an answer.

1. Looks like the distortion arguments only has field-of-view value set (100), but is missing the center X & Y values.
2. Plane2Cylinder is only half of the distortion needed. The subject (mug) is not a perfect cylinder, so an additional slight-distortion (perhaps Perspective) will need to be applied to match the suffice pitch.

Comment: Actually I applied distortion on only that black logo and place onto mug. The second image is the result from Fred's script. Sorry I don't understand it completely but I want to know that is there a possibility to get the result like second image using Plane2Cylinder distortion?

Comment: Can you update the question with the arguments used to achieve the results of Fred's script + source images? Might help

Comment: Plane2cylinder was designed for a specific kind of camera. It was not designed to do what you want. You can use my script, cylinderize, if you are on a Unix-like system.